# RAILS/Ruby error "CALL_AND_RETRY_0: Allocation failed - process out of memory"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, memory, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have my app working at http://rocksuper.bitnamiapp.com/ and it works fine, but when I include the javascript using `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` the page gives me an error that says

**fatal in Public#index** - CALL_AND_RETRY_0: Allocation failed - process out of memory

see this screen shot:

[image]

I wonder how I can fix this error,

Any comments are very welcome..

By the way: I tried removing the

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

and replace it with

`<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" %>`

then It works fine, it didn't gave me an error and the jquery is embedded properly(tested via console).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with custom javascript within your project rather than with the jQuery library. Are you perhaps recursively closing an object?

Try setting a breakpoint just before where a memory error might be occurring within your JS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but I am using the same script in my old server, I just transfer it to amazon ec2. And then after transferring it gave me an error like what I said at the top "CALL_AND_RETRY_0: Allocation failed - process out of memory"